# How to make a basic FullCalendar custom view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

The code below is from FullCalendar's [Custom View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) documentation.  It seems like a great start, but it would be very helpful for someone brand new like me to have some basic code that renders the most simple custom view (with some events).  They tell you to look at BasicView and AgendaView as a reference, but it's a little beyond my understanding.  Are each of the functions required to be overridden in the custom class?

This Plunker has a basic FullCalendar and a button to change to a custom view.  What would be very helpful is to see a working example.  I have been tinkering for hours with no success for a custom view.  If you know FullCalendar and would be willing to fill in some code for the functions it would be very appreciated!

https://plnkr.co/edit/gfEUCVYTWTm1md24e33m?p=preview

My goal is to build a day list that lists all events of the day in order in a scrollable div (where each entry will eventually be quite fleshed out with data and css styling--I'm not sure if listDay would allow for this type of customization??).

```
var FC = $.fullCalendar; // a reference to FullCalendar's root namespace
var View = FC.View;      // the class that all views must inherit from
var CustomView;          // our subclass

CustomView = View.extend({ // make a subclass of View

    initialize: function() {
        // called once when the view is instantiated, when the user switches to the view.
        // initialize member variables or do other setup tasks.
    },

    render: function() {
        // responsible for displaying the skeleton of the view within the already-defined
        // this.el, a jQuery element.
    },

    setHeight: function(height, isAuto) {
        // responsible for adjusting the pixel-height of the view. if isAuto is true, the
        // view may be its natural height, and `height` becomes merely a suggestion.
    },

    renderEvents: function(events) {
        // reponsible for rendering the given Event Objects
    },

    destroyEvents: function() {
        // responsible for undoing everything in renderEvents
    },

    renderSelection: function(range) {
        // accepts a {start,end} object made of Moments, and must render the selection
    },

    destroySelection: function() {
        // responsible for undoing everything in renderSelection
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I've added a few lines to your plunker to make the custom view work. You can find here the example: https://plnkr.co/edit/8iOq15CsL2x6RPt29wgE?p=preview

Just to mention the changes:
In the calendar initializer the view definition has been added

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
    views: {
            CustomView: {
                type: 'custom',
                buttonText: 'my Custom View',
                click:  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'CustomView')
            }
        }
});
```

In the custom view just added this in the render

```
 $('.fc-view').append("<div>Insert your content here</div").css("background", "red");
```

In the custom view you get access to the events by doing this:

```
var myEvents=$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

From there on you can do your further customizations